# Как реализовать подобный эффект?

Tags: jquery, css, parallax

Всем привет! 
Есть сайт: [ссылка](https://www.invisionapp.com/labs)

Насколько я поняла, на сайте реализован горизонтальный и вертикальный параллакс.
При прокрутке страницы, основные элементы (кнопки, заголовки, фигуры и тп) немного двигаются вертикально вверх, а при остановке скролла, фоновые элементы (кружочки, квадратики и тп) двигаются по определенным осям в зависимости от движения мыши.

Может кто-нибудь знает, как реализовать подобный эффект? Буду очень благодарна, если подкинете какие-нибудь плагины, статьи..что угодно.
Спасибо!

Comment: Поищите по плагинам в интернете. Самому такое долго сочинять

Comment: http://codepen.io/search/pens/?q=parallax%20%20mouse&limit=all&order=popularity&depth=everything&show_forks=false  вот здесь подобного вагон , смотрите